# TypeScript: Implementing a generic type-constrained function to instantiate and return instances of a specific type

Tags: typescript, generics, constraints, type-traits

I want to implement a function with the following behavior:

```
GetComponent<T>(type : typeof T): T { ... }
```

I would like this function to accept a constructor as an argument, where the constructor's type is T, and return an instance of type T.

Additionally, I want the function to result in a compilation error if the provided type does not match. (like `GetComponent<Vec2>(Vec3)`).

Is it possible to achieve this functionality?

And if there is any way to forbid the abstracted type to input?

**i had try something like this:**

```
class Resources {
    static Load<T extends AssetObject>(type: typeof AssetObject, id: string): T {
        return Resources.load_sync_impl(id, type) as T;
    }
}
```

but when i try to write List, and i can not find any way to limit the input argument as the type i define in the class:

```
class List<T> {
    constructor(type: any) {   <<======= i had to write it as any so it can support the private constructor class
        this._type = type;
    }
}
```

the old solution is something like

```
constructor(type: new (...args: any[]) => T);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [edit] to make your code a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to clearly see the issue you're having.  Right now there seems to be  pseudocode (e.g., `<<===`, `...`) and undeclared types/values (e.g., `Vec2`, `AssetObject`) so I'm fighting with the code just to get started.  And please make sure it's obvious what the problem is; your "old solution" looks similar to what I'd suggest here, so if there's a problem it would be helpful for you to spell it out for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally found the answer for this question, here is it

```
type Traits_Constructor<T> = T extends Function ? Function : (Function & { prototype: T });
```

and use this trait directly, then problem sloved!

```
GetComponent<T extends Component>(type: Traits_Constructor<T>): T;
```